Codility max profit problem: why accumulated difference sum solution equivalent to 2 index difference solution?
An array A consisting of N integers is given. It contains daily prices of a stock share for a period of N consecutive days. If a single share was bought on day P and sold on day Q, where 0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N, then the profit of such transaction is equal to A[Q] − A[P], provided that A[Q] ≥ A[P]. Otherwise, the transaction brings loss of A[P] − A[Q].

For example, consider the following array A consisting of six elements such that:

  A[0] = 23171
  A[1] = 21011
  A[2] = 21123
  A[3] = 21366
  A[4] = 21013
  A[5] = 21367
If a share was bought on day 0 and sold on day 2, a loss of 2048 would occur because A[2] − A[0] = 21123 − 23171 = −2048. If a share was bought on day 4 and sold on day 5, a profit of 354 would occur because A[5] − A[4] = 21367 − 21013 = 354. Maximum possible profit was 356. It would occur if a share was bought on day 1 and sold on day 5.

Write a function,

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }

that, given an array A consisting of N integers containing daily prices of a stock share for a period of N consecutive days, returns the maximum possible profit from one transaction during this period. The function should return 0 if it was impossible to gain any profit.

For example, given array A consisting of six elements such that:

  A[0] = 23171
  A[1] = 21011
  A[2] = 21123
  A[3] = 21366
  A[4] = 21013
  A[5] = 21367
the function should return 356, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [0..400,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..200,000].

https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/9-maximum_slice_problem/max_profit/
Here is a solution where I found on youtube
function solution(arr) {
    let max = 0;
    let acc = 0;

    for(let i=1; i<arr.length; ++i) {
        const diff = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
        acc = acc + diff;
        if(acc > 0) {
            if(acc > max) {
                max = acc;
            }
        } else {
            acc = 0;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

my question is below:
In this test case above, we know that array[five] - array[one] = 356 (we buy at day 5 and sell at day 1 to get max profit), in one transaction. We do not consider anything in between and that is what the question is asking
Using the accumulated difference sum and add them up together (hence other numbers come in and interference the calculation)
Why accumulated difference sum is equivalent to array[five] - array[one] = 356?


Please don't format non-code as code, at least for long lines. Very inconvenient having to scroll sideways to read the text.

Consider the case of just three elements. It is clear that arr[i + 2] - arr[i + 1] + arr[i + 1] - arr[i] = arr[i + 2] - arr[i] as the term arr[i + 1] cancels out.
More generally, the sum arr[i + 1] - arr[i] as i ranges from start to end - 1 is a telescoping sum that equals arr[end] - arr[start]. You can rigorously prove this by summation properties or induction.
Based on this, after converting the array of prices to a difference array, the answer is the maximum subarray sum, which can be found with Kadane's Algorithm.

I think I got this point: it will cancel out. The algo code from my post have a reset i.e. acc = 0, when acc < 0. Say arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0, reset to zero, then 0 + arr[i + 2] - arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 2] - arr[i]? Could you clarify the reset behaviour?

@kenpeter You can consider it as two separate steps. First convert the array to an array of differences. Then, find the maximum subarray sum on this difference array. One method to do this in linear time is Kadane's Algorithm, which resets the sum to 0 when it becomes negative.

@kenpeter In any case, there's a simpler solution to this that doesn't require doing this manipulation anyway.

all good. Could you explain that: in pure subarray problem, we either use prev + curr OR curr (reset). in difference subarray problem (after converting to kadane's), it becomes prev + 0 OR 0 (reset). I try to connect curr and 0 in these 2 similar questions.

@kenpeter Those are just variations of Kadane's algorithm; it has nothing to do with taking differences or not. If an empty subarray is allowed, then the sum is reset to 0; if a subarray must have length at least 1, then you take the maximum with the current element. Here, empty subarrays can be considered allowed because the problem states that 0 should be returned if there is no way to make any profit.
